# Xcode keyboard shortcut to jump directly to main editor window?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an Xcode keyboard shortcut to jump directly to main editor window?

Cmd+J seems to be the closest, but it displays a UI for selecting which editor to open, or to open a new assistant editor.

Comment: I think you should ask this type of question on Apple developer's Forum...

Answer (score 1):

No there is no XCode Keyboard shortcut to jump directly to main editor window. But yes <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> allows you to move to editor window. I am attaching a picture of probably all the shortcuts for `XCode 4`. I found this on a blog... The picture is quite big so you will have to zoom.

[image]

Comment: Cmd+J shows the UI to select which window to jump to, and doesn't directly jump to the main editor window.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command in `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Key Bindings` that is called `Move Focus To Next Editor (Navigate Menu)`.
With it you jump to the main Editor and if you are in the main Editor you jump to the next editor until you had focus on all editors then you jump back to the main one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html) and this [blog](http://nshipster.com/xcode-key-bindings-and-gestures/) about Xcode shortcuts.

Xcode also has a pretty complete "Key Bindings" section in its preferences.